# Sum over range interval within case sql statment

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, window-functions

I'm trying to get the average spend for every date *after* the start date of each customer (this is for the purposes of Recency-Frequency-Monetary analysis). This is the monetary_value element below for which I want to get the sum of all transactions after the start date of the customer divided by the count of the days they purchased on. I'm using Oracle 12c.

I have the following which works, but includes the full date range.

```
RFM AS (
SELECT SRC_USER_ID,
  COUNT(distinct PICKUP_DATE) -1 as frequency,
  (MAX(PICKUP_DATE) - MIN(PICKUP_DATE)) as recency,
  (TO_DATE ('2018/05/12', 'yyyy/mm/dd') - MIN(PICKUP_DATE)) as T,
  (CASE WHEN COUNT(distinct PICKUP_DATE)-1=0 THEN 0 ELSE
         SUM(PRICE_TOTAL)/COUNT(distinct PICKUP_DATE) END) AS monetary_value
FROM TRANSACTIONS
group by SRC_USER_ID
```

I gather that I need to use a Window Aggregate Function (https://ss64.com/ora/syntax-analytic-aggregate.html). However when I try the below it does not work.

```
RFM AS (
SELECT SRC_USER_ID,
  COUNT(distinct PICKUP_DATE) -1 as frequency,
  (MAX(PICKUP_DATE) - MIN(PICKUP_DATE)) as recency,
  (TO_DATE ('2018/05/12', 'yyyy/mm/dd') - MIN(PICKUP_DATE)) as T,
  (CASE WHEN COUNT(distinct PICKUP_DATE)-1=0 THEN 0 ELSE
    SUM(PRICE_TOTAL) OVER (ORDER BY PICKUP_DATE) RANGE INTERVAL '1' DAY FOLLOWING UNBOUNDED/COUNT(distinct PICKUP_DATE) END) AS monetary_value
FROM TRANSACTIONS
group by SRC_USER_ID
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you prepared sample test input data and the expected result for this data, preferably using one of these sites: http://sqlfiddle.com/ or  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2  

Looking at these queries, it is difficult to guess what is going on, and I'm not sure if this function would be the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When learning about analytic functions, it is probably a good idea to have a look at the examples in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) and [oracle-base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions).  Here's a little test table, with 3 columns whose names are similar to the ones in your query. (Note: The dates and prices are random values.)

```
create table transactions
as
select
  mod( level, 3 ) + 1 as srcuserid
, to_date( trunc( dbms_random.value( 2451925, 2458258 ) ), 'J' ) pickupdate
, round( dbms_random.value() * 10000, 2 ) pricetotal
from dual
connect by level <= 12 ;

select * from transactions order by srcuserid, pickupdate ;

SRCUSERID  PICKUPDATE  PRICETOTAL  
1          27-JUL-03   9447.05     
1          04-APR-05   9595.6      
1          28-SEP-07   408.09      
1          16-AUG-13   5643.33     
2          20-JAN-01   6253.87     
2          26-OCT-05   5981.7      
2          16-DEC-08   8138.03     
2          20-JUL-17   49.67       
3          08-AUG-03   7411.74     
3          29-OCT-06   2218.95     
3          11-FEB-10   111.07      
3          26-JUL-17   600.15  

12 rows selected.
```

For developing your query, try to use analytic functions that will calculate the values for all columns (as required).  Avoid using GROUP BY for this, as it will throw a "not a GROUP BY expression" error in this situation.  Also, you will find that the result set contains a row for each row in the original table.  You can use DISTINCT here, as we are only dealing with aggregates.

```
select distinct -- without "distinct", you'll get a multiple identical rows "per window"
  srcuserid
, count( pickupdate ) over ( partition by srcuserid ) as frequency
, max( pickupdate ) over ( partition by srcuserid )   as max_date
, min( pickupdate ) over ( partition by srcuserid )   as min_date
, sum( pricetotal ) over ( partition by srcuserid )   as sum_pricetotal
from transactions 
-- group by srcuserid  -- ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
;

SRCUSERID  FREQUENCY  MAX_DATE   MIN_DATE   SUM_PRICETOTAL  
2          4          20-JUL-17  20-JAN-01  20423.27        
3          4          26-JUL-17  08-AUG-03  10341.91        
1          4          16-AUG-13  27-JUL-03  25094.07
```

Once this (kind of) works, use the query as an inline view, and add some finishing touches to the outer SELECT.  Note that the final query here also uses first_value() - which may be a way for you to find the first entry of the "window" as it were.

```
select
  srcuserid
, count_ - 1          as frequency
, max_date - min_date as recency
, trunc( sysdate - min_date )  as T
, case
    when count_ - 1 = 0 then 0
    else round( ( sum_pricetotal - firstpricetotal ) / ( count_ - 1 ), 2 ) 
  end as monetary_value 
from (
  select distinct
    srcuserid
  , count( pickupdate ) over ( partition by srcuserid ) as count_
  , max( pickupdate ) over ( partition by srcuserid )   as max_date
  , min( pickupdate ) over ( partition by srcuserid )   as min_date
  , sum( pricetotal ) over ( partition by srcuserid )   as sum_pricetotal
-- first_value(): find the first ie oldest "pricetotal" for each client
  , first_value( pricetotal ) over ( 
      partition by srcuserid order by pickupdate )      as firstpricetotal
  from transactions
) 
;

-- result
SRCUSERID  FREQUENCY  RECENCY  T     MONETARY_VALUE  
2          3          6025     6328  4723.13         
3          3          5101     5398  976.72          
1          3          3673     5410  5215.67
```

See also: [dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=83968bbb79c4b4e96ead1f91dc2cbfea).

Comment: That's awesome thanks! I had gotten there in the end with 4 CTEs, but this is much nicer and faster. There is one detail left which what you have doesn't line up with what I'm looking for. Multiple transactions occur per day, so I want the aggregate for them (e.g. firstpricetotal should be over the first day). Is it a small change to include that?

Comment: replacing transactions with ((SELECT srcuserid,
        sum(pricetotal) AS pricetotal,
        pickupdate
      FROM transactions
    GROUP BY srcuserid, pickupdate) 
does the trick. Thanks again, much appreciated, now means I can put this into production without needing python.

Comment: Brilliant!  You've found out how to "make the windows smaller". (You could also try  (partition by srcuserid, pickupdate) if time allows it ... )   Thanks for your feedback. Best of luck!